# Android GoogleApiClient never connects or fails. Does nothing

Tags: android, google-api-client

Attempting to connect to GoogleApiClient, but running into one of those situations where instead of getting an error, nothing happens at all.

```
public class Locator
        extends Activity
        implements
        LocationListener, 
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location        mLastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_atmbranch_locator);

        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
        // Note: This does get called
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // This never gets called
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        // This never gets called
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // This never gets called
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // This never gets called
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add permission in manifest ?

Comment: Yes, I have this in the manifest:
    "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>"
Its directly under <manifest> though, outside <application>

Comment: Ok, I think this might have been some sport of weird break point issue with Android Studio. I tried again after restarting and it worked fine.